# use asp:botton to send data by jquery ajax in asp Web app

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

> I want to control and send my data by Ajax .but on click  event does not work.my code ?works in website but I have problem in Webform Web application .what is the problem?
>
> ### this is my ajax :

```
enter code here
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#BtnLogin").click(function (event) {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "defualt.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
         data: '{name: "' + $('#<%= TXTUsername.ClientID %>')[0].value + 'pass:' + $("#<%= TXTPassword.ClientID %>")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
         });
      });
     });
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        // alert(response.d);
        $('#other').html("<span>لطفا کمی تامل کنید</span>");
    }
enter code here
```

Comment: Your problem is that you did not provide your code in the question. We aren't telepathic, we can't tell you what you did wrong without you providing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You  can rearrange your json like below and in ajax call `JSON.stringify()` it

```
var myJson = {
name: $('#<%= TXTUsername.ClientID %>')[0].value,
pass: $('#<%= TXTPassword.ClientID %>')[0].value
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#BtnLogin").click(function (event) {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "defualt.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
         data: JSON.stringify(myJson),
         //rest is the same ...
     });
```